# Query array items

Tags: mongodb

Can someone please help me constructing and extracting data from below JSON using mongo query?

JSON:

```
{
"app": [{
    "appFamily": "default",
    "attributes": [{
            "name": "field1",
            "value": "field1value"
        },
        {
            "name": "field2",
            "value": "field2value"
        },
        {
            "name": "field3",
            "value": "field3value"
        }
    ],
    "nameApp": "AppName",
},
       {
    "appFamily": "default2",
    "attributes": [{
            "name": "field1",
            "value": "field1value"
        },
        {
            "name": "field2",
            "value": "field2value"
        },
        {
            "name": "field3",
            "value": "field3value"
        }
    ],
    "nameApp": "AppName2",
}]
```

}

I need to fetch fields and values where name = "field2" and "field3" along with "nameApp" value.

Expected output:

```
{
{
    {
        "name": "field2",
        "value": "field2value"
    }, {
        "name": "field3",
        "value": "field3value"
    },
    "name": "AppName",
}, {

    {
        "name": "field2",
        "value": "field2value"
    },
    {
        "name": "field3",
        "value": "field3value"
    },
    "name": "AppName2",

}
```

}

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tarun, assuming "app" is your Collection, you could make this call using *find* with the *$or* and *$elemMatch* [logical operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/), like this:

```
db.app.find(
    { $or: [
        { attributes: { $elemMatch: { name: 'field2' } }},
        { attributes: { $elemMatch: { name: 'field3' } }}
    ] }
);
```

It might be difficult (or impossible) to return expected output you listed, I'm not sure. Are you okay with the *attributes* being returned in an Array?

If so, you can do that explicitly by including the name of the field and a 1 in the query [like this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/):

```
db.app.find(
    { $or: [
        { attributes: { $elemMatch: { name: 'field2' } }},
        { attributes: { $elemMatch: { name: 'field3' } }}
      ]
    }, { attributes: 1, nameApp: 1}
);
```

If "app" is the document, you'll need to nest the query above with another *$elemMatch* operator - $elemMatch is what allows you to match elements of an array.